# waiting for the map problem

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-saver, ros-hydro, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the tutorial " slam_gmapping Tutorials MappingFromLoggedData " ,
and when I enter this command " rosrun map_server map saver " , I have this message " waiting for the map "
and after there are nothing.
What is the problem, I had forgot a step, or any configuration?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/170426/waiting-for-the-map-problem/) by [guigui](https://answers.ros.org/users/16871/guigui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/13506/rizwan/) on 2014-05-29**:
same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

type the command rosrun map_server map_saver -f my_map

---

Originally posted by [hrishikesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/23412/hrishikesh/) with karma: 16 on 2015-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0